# How to figure out what the Android Software Update is?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update

I just received a "Software update" and in the details it says important [sarcasm] stuff like:

> Size: 91.45 MB
>   Improved stability.
>   [WARNING: The devices will be restarted during the installation process.]
>   Caution: ... blah blah about you can't use your phone during install.

but it doesn't state which version I'm updating to.

#### Phone details

> **Phone**: Samsung Galaxy S4
>   **Model**: GT-I9505
>   **Android**: 4.4.2
>   **Build**: KOT49H
>   **Baseband**: I9505XXUGNG8
>   **Carrier**: unknown

It's secondhand phone, I think German/Austrian because it keeps installing some weird apps with german names on every OS update. I bought it in the UK and currently using it in Hungary.

#### News / 5.0

When I search for new news articles about S4 and OTA today, I find [Android 5.0 Lollipop OTA finally arrives for Galaxy S4 Google Play Edition](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/android-5-0-lollipop-ota-finally-arrives-galaxy-s4-google-play-edition-1479355), there are a few problems with this:

- I don't think I have Google Play Edition, because I have TouchWiz
- I don't believe S4 would get 5.0 sooner than my Nexus 7 (1st edition)
- I cannot believe an 5.0 update would be 90MB...

I'm really looking for some authoritative info on whether it's 4.4.3 or 4.4.4, because I want to avoid 4.4.3. Even the build number of the update would help a lot. By authoritative info I mean that it's possible to find out next time it happens without asking again. Maybe a global list of baseband/build numbers?

Comment: I admit it's annoying that I couldn't even get any info regarding the update on search engine. Searching for `size 91.45 MB improved stability samsung galaxy` returned nothing :(

Comment: Your updates typically come from the cell carrier. Have you checked their web site?

Comment: @rrirower the question has a body for a reason, please read the "Phone details" section! Note: I also have an S3 bought from CarphoneWarehouse without SIM, what is the cell carrier there?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a few methods I could think of:

- Wireshark the WiFi packets -> nothing
- `adb logcat` to see if anything extra info is logged -> nothing
  I found out thought, that most of what we see on the "Update" screen is hard-coded and only the "Improved stability..." part is dynamic.
- `adb pull /cache/fota/update.zip` or `adb pull /data/fota/update.zip` -> requires root

After almost giving up I found http://sammobile.com. The sad thing is that it only works for Samsung phones, which I have luckily. The fact that my phone's origin is German or Austrian and the date the update showed up helped me narrow it down to
[12-11-2014 Firmware Updates](http://www.sammobile.com/2014/12/11/12-11-2014-firmware-updates-galaxy-gear-galaxy-note-3-lte-galaxy-s4-mini-and-more/):

```
Germany (DBT)                   GT-I9505    GALAXY S4 LTE   4.4.2   I9505XXUGNK4
Germany (Black Edition)(DBT)    GT-I9505    GALAXY S4 LTE   4.4.2   I9505XXUGNG8
```

and since I already have `I9505XXUGNG8`, it must be the first one, which is weird because I would swear [the color is black like this](https://www.t-mobile.de/shop/handy/0,,2963-_314605-0-12775;CNC-0,00.html)

Then I checked the carrier's listing: 
http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9505/DBT/ which seems to correspond with the timings of my past received the updates. So I checked my CSC (`*#1234#`) and found that indeed [this is my current version](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/33356/I9505XXUGNG8_I9505OXAGNG8_DBT.zip/) so the [update is still 4.4.2](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/40046/I9505XXUGNK4_I9505OXAGNK4_DBT.zip/).

### Edit

I did the update and after checking *About device* it was indeed updated to `I9505XXUGNK4`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in general, only for *Samsung*s. I'll leave the question open in case anyone has a better way of telling.